# How to  request a terms-component in solr shard?

Tags: solr, lucene

How to  request a terms-component in solr shard ?

Answer (score 1):

Check SOLR wiki for Distributed Search Support, it's available since Solr 3.1:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent